# How to deserialize records from Kafka using Structured Streaming in Java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I use Spark **2.1**.

I am trying to read records from Kafka using Spark Structured Streaming, deserialize them and apply aggregations afterwards.

I have the following code:

```java
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
        .builder()
        .appName("Statistics")
        .getOrCreate();

Dataset<Row> df = spark
        .readStream()
        .format("kafka")
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaUri)
        .option("subscribe", "Statistics")
        .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
        .load();

df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
```

What I want is to deserialize the `value` field into my object instead of casting as `String`.

I have a custom deserializer for this.

```
public StatisticsRecord deserialize(String s, byte[] bytes)
```

How can I do this in Java?

---

The only relevant link I have found is this https://databricks.com/blog/2017/04/26/processing-data-in-apache-kafka-with-structured-streaming-in-apache-spark-2-2.html, but this is for Scala.

Comment: Are your messages in JSON format?

Comment: I can store the data either in JSON or serialized via custom serializer.

Answer (score 4):

Define schema for your JSON messages.

```
StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[] { 
                DataTypes.createStructField("Id", DataTypes.IntegerType, false),
                DataTypes.createStructField("Name", DataTypes.StringType, false),
                DataTypes.createStructField("DOB", DataTypes.DateType, false) });
```

Now read Messages like below. MessageData is JavaBean for your JSON message.

```
Dataset<MessageData> df = spark
            .readStream()
            .format("kafka")
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaUri)
            .option("subscribe", "Statistics")
            .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
            .load()
            .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING) as message")
            .select(functions.from_json(functions.col("message"),schema).as("json"))
            .select("json.*")
            .as(Encoders.bean(MessageData.class));
```

Comment: The schema is correctly applied, but I get null values for all columns. I am trying to read the columns as df.createOrReplaceTempView("data"); StreamingQuery query = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM data").writeStream().format("console").start(); Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You can read the Dataset<MessageData> df directly like below. df.writeStream().format("console").start();

Comment: This produced the exact same results. I see the top 20 rows with "null" in all columns.

Comment: `null` are when `from_json` could not deJSONify the input.

Comment: Thanks Jacek Laskowski. @dchar Please check your kafka messages as from_json function says "Returns `null`, in the case of an unparseable string."

Comment: I have JSON with hundreds of fields, how is it feasible to create struct for that large pojo ?

Comment: @dchar I have faced same issue and found out that i was passing doubletype in json and reading the value as integertype , so please check the types you are passing and reading.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a custom deserializer in Java for your data, use it on bytes that you get from Kafka after `load`.

```
df.select("value")
```

That line gives you `Dataset<Row>` with just a single column `value`.

---

I'm exclusively with Spark API for Scala so I'd do the following in Scala to handle the "deserialization" case:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
implicit val statisticsRecordEncoder = Encoders.product[StatisticsRecord]
val myDeserializerUDF = udf { bytes => deserialize("hello", bytes) }
df.select(myDeserializerUDF($"value") as "value_des")
```

That should give you what you want...in Scala. Converting it to Java is your home exercise :)

Mind that your custom object has to have an encoder available or Spark SQL will refuse to put its objects inside a Dataset.