# How to implement custom deserializer for Kafka stream using Spark structured streaming?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to migrate my current streaming app, which is based on using RDDs (from [their documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html)) to their new Datasets API using structured streaming, which I'm told is the preferred approach to do real time streaming with Spark these days.

Currently I have the app setup to consume from 1 topic called "SATELLITE", that has messages containing a key timestamp and value containing a `Satellite` POJO. But I'm having problems figuring out how to implement a deserializer for this. In the my current app it is easy, you just add a line to your like kafka properties map `kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", SatelliteMessageDeserializer.class);`
I'm doing this in Java, which is presenting the biggest challenge, because all the solutions appear to be in Scala, which I don't understand well and I'm not easily able to convert Scala code to Java code.

I followed an example for JSON outlined in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43934180/how-to-deserialize-records-from-kafka-using-structured-streaming-in-java?rq=1), which currently works, but seems overly complex for what I need to do. Given that I already have custom deserializer made for this purpose, I don't see why I should have to cast it to a string first, only to just convert it to JSON, to then convert it to my desired class type. I've also been trying to use some of the examples I found [here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders), but I've had no luck so far.

Currently my app looks like this (using the json approach):

```
import common.model.Satellite;
import org.apache.spark.sql.*;
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;

public class SparkStructuredStreaming  implements Runnable{

    private String bootstrapServers;
    private SparkSession session;

    public SparkStructuredStreaming(final String bootstrapServers, final SparkSession session) {
        this.bootstrapServers = bootstrapServers;
        this.session = session;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Dataset<Row> df = session
                .readStream()
                .format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServers)
                .option("subscribe", "SATELLITE")
                .load();

        StructType schema =  DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[] {
                DataTypes.createStructField("id", DataTypes.StringType, true),
                DataTypes.createStructField("gms", DataTypes.StringType, true),
                DataTypes.createStructField("satelliteId", DataTypes.StringType, true),
                DataTypes.createStructField("signalId", DataTypes.StringType, true),
                DataTypes.createStructField("cnr", DataTypes.DoubleType, true),
                DataTypes.createStructField("constellation", DataTypes.StringType, true),
                DataTypes.createStructField("timestamp", DataTypes.TimestampType, true),
                DataTypes.createStructField("mountPoint", DataTypes.StringType, true),
                DataTypes.createStructField("pseudorange", DataTypes.DoubleType, true),
                DataTypes.createStructField("epochTime", DataTypes.IntegerType, true)
        });

            Dataset<Satellite> df1 = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING) as message")
                    .select(functions.from_json(functions.col("message"),schema).as("json"))
                    .select("json.*")
                    .as(Encoders.bean(Satellite.class));

        try {
            df1.writeStream()
                    .format("console")
                    .option("truncate", "false")
                    .start()
                    .awaitTermination();

        } catch (StreamingQueryException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And I have a custom deserializer that looks like this

```
import common.model.Satellite;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.Map;

public class SatelliteMessageDeserializer implements Deserializer<Satellite> {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SatelliteMessageDeserializer.class);
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public void configure(Map configs, boolean isKey) {
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
    }

    @Override
    public Satellite deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.readValue(new String(data, "UTF-8"), getMessageClass());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Unable to deserialize message {}", data, e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected Class<Satellite> getMessageClass() {
        return Satellite.class;
    }
}
```

How can I use my custom deserializer from within the `SparkStructuredStreaming` class? I am using Spark 2.4, OpenJDK 10 and Kafka 2.0

EDIT: I've tried creating my own UDF, which I think is how this is supposed to be done, but I'm not sure how to get it to return a specific type, as it only seems to allow me to use those in the `Datatypes` class!

```
UserDefinedFunction mode = udf(
                (byte[] bytes) -> deserializer.deserialize("", bytes), DataTypes.BinaryType //Needs to be type Satellite, but only allows ones of type DataTypes
        );

Dataset df1 = df.select(mode.apply(col("value")));
```

Answer (score -1):

`from_json` can only work on string typed Columns.

[Structured Streaming always consumes the Kafka values as bytes](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#kafka-specific-configurations)

> Values are always deserialized as byte arrays with ByteArrayDeserializer. Use DataFrame operations to explicitly deserialize the values

Therefore, you would first at least be deserializing to a String, but I don't think you really need that.

It might be possible to just do this

```
df.select(value).as(Encoders.bean(Satellite.class))
```

If that doesn't work, what you could try is define your own UDF/Decoder so that you could have something like `SATELLITE_DECODE(value)`

In scala

```
object SatelliteDeserializerWrapper {
    val deser = new SatelliteDeserializer
}
spark.udf.register("SATELLITE_DECODE", (topic: String, bytes: Array[Byte]) => 
    SatelliteDeserializerWrapper.deser.deserialize(topic, bytes)
)

df.selectExpr("""SATELLITE_DECODE("topic1", value) AS message""")
```

see [this post for inspiration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43940526/2308683), and also mentioned [in Databricks blog](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/04/26/processing-data-in-apache-kafka-with-structured-streaming-in-apache-spark-2-2.html)

Comment: I tried both approaches, but neither have worked. Could you take a look at my edit, where I show how I'm trying to implement a UDF. I need it to return a type of `Satellite` but it only seems to allow me to return types from the `DataTypes` class. I'm not sure how to get around this. Currently it throws a `ClassCastException`

Comment: In the Java API, I think you'll need to make your own struct type https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/DataTypes.html#createStructType-java.util.List-