# How to process the dataframe which was read from Kafka Topic using Spark Streaming

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming, spark-kafka-integration

I'm able to stream twitter data into my Kafka topic via a producer. When I try to consume through the default Kafka consumer I'm able to see the tweets as well.

[image]

But when I try to use Spark Streaming to consume this and process further, I'm unable to find resources to refer. This is how my consumer looks like:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import time

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('LinkitTest').getOrCreate()

df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
  .option("subscribe", "tweets") \
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
  .load()

#df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")

print(df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)"))

query = df.writeStream.format("console").start()
import time
time.sleep(10) # sleep 10 seconds
query.stop()
```

Even when I do `spark-submit` I see the tweets in the topic but the value aren't readable

> spark-submit --packages
> org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.0.1 kafka_consumer.py

[image]

I'm unable to figure out how to at least print the column values (or the tweets in this case) with the dataframe I have? Any help could be appriecated

**UPDATE**

I was able to print the values on the console, but as you see its not readable. How can I convert this to a readable String?

```
query = df.select(col("value"))\
  .writeStream\
  .format("console")\
  .start()
```

[image]

Comment: As the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#kafka-specific-configurations) says "Values are always deserialized as byte arrays with ByteArrayDeserializer. Use DataFrame operations to explicitly deserialize the values.".
Please look at this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43934180/how-to-deserialize-records-from-kafka-using-structured-streaming-in-java 
is it a solution to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
print(df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)"))
```

You want

```
df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)").show()
```

But that is for batch dataframes, not streaming ones. For streaming ones, then you need to cast before writing.

```
df.select(col("value").cast("string"))\
  .writeStream\
  .format("console")\
```

> Twitter data into Kafka via a producer

You don't need Spark for this. You can use tweepy and `kafka-python` directly.